# How to prevent POST requests from ajax (obtained through firebug)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, security, xmlhttprequest

How would I prevent users from spamming a post request? For example, a form is submitted via Ajax post. Using firebug I can see the post request, but I noticed that this request can be easily repeated by right clicking on it and selecting "open in a new tab" How can I prevent something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any web form can be posted to in any number of ways. What you need to do is make sure the server-side script that processes the form has the logic needed to "ignore" spammy requests.

Answer (score 3):

When a valid user logs in or begins a session, generate a random token string and place it in a hidden form field.  Each time a valid post is made by a valid user, generate a random token string and store it in `$_SESSION` while also returning it to the client browser.  When a the browser makes another Ajax post request, it must also send that token string which you compare against the `$_SESSION`.

That way you can only make an Ajax post if your server has previously sanctioned it.  It prevents anyone who simply knows the Ajax handler's URL from sending HTTP requests to it.

Comment: Everything is fine but there is no need to generate token each requst. 1 token per session is enough.

Comment: @zerkms I regard the token regeneration as extra insurance against CSRF, should the user's traffic get intercepted without SSL.  That token gets invalidated quickly, so a prolonged session impersonation isn't possible.

Comment: long-living CSRF token is not less secure. And with 1-token-per-request you'll get a headache with several tabs.

Comment: @zerkms Agree about the headache with multiple tabs.

Comment: what about security? ;-) If traffic has been intercepted and site doesn't use ssl - then interceptor *already has login credentials*.

Comment: @zerkms If only momentarily intercepted (like in a coffee shop) and the login was not compromised-- compromised sessionid can't be used for an ajax post unless the site is actually visited first to generate a new token. Probably better to just regenerate sessionid :)

Comment: too many if's ;-) The solution either works or not. I would never choose the one you suggested, but I respect your point of view (that is why I +1'd this answer few hours ago)

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably. But you can check for the [`HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`](http://snipplr.com/view/16624/) header which is *usually* send along with ajax requests. It can be spoofed though, and can also not be there for genuine ajax requests.

Comment: If it can be spoofed - what is the reason of using it?

Comment: It gives an indication of what is an ajax request. Michael's answer if a far better method, so long as it's a token per request. If it isn't that, then there's nothing stopping a user doing *exactly* what the OP says they want to stop. You're right that it gets painful with multiple tabs, but that's exactly what the OP is trying to prevent.

Comment: even with 1-token-per-request neither your or Michael's solution can prevent automated posting. Just implement some client code that requests page to get new valid token and post, repeat then infinitely. Ta-dah